# NetBeans IDE 8.2 not displaying error messages

Tags: java, netbeans, compiler-errors

My `NetBeans` does not show the error message. It only shows a black box on the line of error.

I intentionally removed the semi-colon just to show the problem. Any ideas on how to fix/display the error message? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Just a suggestion. Try restarting netbeans and see the problem still exists.

Comment: check your jdk version into netbeans and use jdk 1.7 or 1.7 then Restart your netbeans and clean and rebuild yoyr project

Comment: I'm using JDK 1.8 (64 bit) though. Restarting won't help either

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed something in [NB_INSTALL_FOLDER]\etc\netbeans.conf?

If yes, just try to change it back and restart NetBeans and see if it works now.

If no, close NetBeans open the netbeans.conf in a editor and change the part of the property `netbeans_default_options` where it says `-J-Dsun.java2d.dpiaware=true` to `false` and start NetBeans again, maybe that helps, otherwise you could also try to change `-J-Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true` to `false`, too

Comment: Sadly, it did not work :( I have sent a bug report to the NetBeans team though. Thanks anyway!

Comment: You're welcome, I'm sure they can help you. Did you post your bug into the new [Jira Issue Tracker of NetBeans](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS) or in the old one?